# How To Set Up Multiple WordPress Sites on a Single Ubuntu Instance with an Nginx VPS

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, ubuntu, nginx

I have two domain names (e.g. site1.com and site2.com) with CNAMES setup to run the blogs (e.g. blog.site1.com and blog.site2.com). On a separate server I am running VPS (NGINX) server with a mysql-server to run the two wordpress blogs.

The bests guidance I can find is at this [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-multiple-wordpress-sites-on-a-single-ubuntu-vps). However, they are using an Apache virtual host. So with Nginx I did the following:

```
cd /etc/nginx/sites-available

sudo cp default site1.com
sudo cp default site2.com
```

In the site1.com server block I modified the following:

```
server {
   listen 80 default_server;
   listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

   #root /usr/share/nginx/html;
   root /home/ubuntu/www/blog.site1.com;         
   index index.php;

   server_name blog.site1.com;

   location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        # With php5-fpm:
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

The similar changes were setup for site2.com nginx server block as well. Then symbolic links were setup for the ~/sites-enabled/ files. Then I changed the wp-config.php for each wordpress directory in site1.com and site2.com.

**site1.com (wp-config.php)**

```
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'FirstDatabase');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'FirstUser');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'FirstPassword');
```

**site2.com (wp-config.php)**

```
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'SecondDatabase');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'SecondUser');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'SecondPassword');
```

When I navigate to either blog.site1.com or blog.site2.com I see the wordpress installation page.

[image: WordPress Installation Page]

The problem occurs after I complete the installation for one of the wordpress sites. Even though I have specified separate DB's for each wordpress install instance, both sites show the same wordpress instance. Since the wp-config.php file is clearly showing separate definitions, I am unsure where the error is. Could someone provide guidance for correcting this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Nginx is a tricky beast.  I would recommend removing the `default_server` blocks and explicitly specifying IPs. I don't know why but in my experience nginx gets funky with multiple default servers or when you don't provide IP addresses.

I would not copy it directly as my rewrite conditional seems to be frowned upon by people who know what they are doing? Also I don't use fpm. Theres about 12 exact copies of this and all the domains load without issue.

```
server {
  listen 198.91.xx.xxx:80;

  server_name xxxxxx.org www.xxxxxx.org;

  access_log /home/xxxxxx/logs/xxxxxx.org.access.log;
  error_log /home/xxxxxx/logs/xxxxxx.org.error.log;

  root /home/xxxxxx/domains/xxxxxx.org/public_html/;
  index index.php index.html index.htm;

  if (!-e $request_filename) {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1 last;
  }

  # serve static files directly
  location ~* ^.+.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico)$ {
    expires           30d;
  }

  #location /indexlocation/ {
  #    autoindex on;
  #}
 location ~ .php$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/xxxxxx.socket;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
  }
}
```

Comment: I added the IP to the server block and removed all the default configuration in both blocks (again both external domains were displaying the same wordpress instance). I then worked on your example provided, however, the nginx reload failed. Is there any other part you could suggest for getting two wordpress instances to work on the same server?

Comment: Without seeing both sites-available files and the nginx.conf file I am not sure how much more help I can offer however my main suspect is either somethings off in one of them or its not loading one causing the other to be used as a default. Theres no real "Host 2 Wordpress" tutorials, it would just be 2 separate domains.

My best recommendation would be to seek assistance from the nginx community if you continue to have issues. Nginx is not as frequently used by smaller groups or websites as Apache is so there may be fewer people who can help you here.  http://forum.nginx.org/list.php?11